# check if task with specific method is already running

Tags: c#, task

I have async method `OnValueChange` where i call static method as a task, my method is updating gui with help of Iprogress intereface and my method is returning Image:

```
  public async void OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
      var progress = new Progress<int>(i => ProgresBar.Value = i);

      Image im = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyStaticClass.MyStaticFunction(progress),
      TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

      Picture = im;
  }
```

In some cases i am calling OnValueChange function frequently in short period of time, but i want only one task running at time.

what is most efficient method to check if task with specific method is already running?

Comment: Task.Status is probably what your looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid `async void`. On a side note, I explain on my blog that [the way you're using `StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (you should use `Task.Run` instead).

Applying both of these guidelines to your example, the code will look like this:

```
public async Task OnValueChangeAsync() 
{
  var progress = new Progress<int>(i => ProgresBar.Value = i);
  Image im = await Task.Run(() => MyStaticClass.MyStaticFunction(progress));
  Picture = im;
}

public async void OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  await OnValueChangeAsync();
}
```

At this point, it becomes more clear how to detect whether a method is already running (since that method actually returns a `Task` now). One implementation is as such:

```
private async Task OnValueChangeImplAsync()
{
  var progress = new Progress<int>(i => ProgresBar.Value = i);
  Image im = await Task.Run(() => MyStaticClass.MyStaticFunction(progress));
  Picture = im;
  _onValueChangeTask = null;
}

private Task _onValueChangeTask;
public Task OnValueChangeAsync()
{
  if (_onValueChangeTask != null)
    return _onValueChangeTask;
  _onValueChangeTask = OnValueChangeImplAsync();
  return _onValueChangeTask;
}

public async void OnValueChange(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  await OnValueChangeAsync();
}
```

Comment: for example OnValueChangeImplAsync() taking one parameter like OnValueChangeImplAsync(int CustomerId) and we need run only one task for per customer. Then How you can handle this situation? will you use List?

Comment: @virender I recommend you ask your own question, with specifics for your own situation. While you could use something like a dictionary, getting it all right without memory leaks is difficult. There may be an easier solution, depending on the specifics of your situation.